# Limit frontblock to display articles/stories only in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am new to drupal, so sorry for this noob question, but I was wondering how to display articles only in the central column. Currently there are also blog entries, etc and I would like to get rid of them. I have a Views plugin installed but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View create a filter for Node: Type. Here, you can tell it specifically what kind of content to show.

Comment: I've done this, but still other types of nodes appear within the front block.

Comment: How is your View setup? Are you sure that it is the view being output and not the default Drupal frontpage which shows all nodes? If it were the view being output you would definitely see specific content.

Comment: I have  a frontpage view but I cannot delete it. When I create new view for articles it doesnt work.

Comment: Change your Drupal frontpage from /node to something else like index.htm. The default Drupal frontpage is not generated from Views. The Publishing options 'Promote to Frontpage' and 'Sticky at the top of Lists' control what is shown on the default frontpage. I usually create a node and make it the homepage, and from there, I can add View blocks or override it with Panels.

Comment: Still not sure what to do and I cannot find any tutorial for this simple thing!I manage to create a block with articles that appears at the top of the frontpage section, but other articles are still there.How to change drupal frontpage from node to index.htm?

Comment: Create a Page node, give its path index.htm. Under Site Information, you can change the default front page of Drupal and give it a path. Here, set it to index.htm. This will stop the default presentation of nodes from being shown and you now have front page control. http://drupal.org/node/15364

Answer (score 0):

you can change your frontpage settings in admin/settings/site-information

so let's say you created a view - with a page display
set the page url of your view (eg. articles), and then in your settings (the path i mentioned before) you set the drupal frontpage to the page path of your view (that would be 'articles')

i hope that's clear enough for you